# Limit configured cafile to public npm repo

Tags: npm, repository, config

My ~/.npmrc has:

`cafile=/etc/ssl/cert.pem`

which lets me access the public npm repo through our corporate firewall.
It also sets a custom repo like:

`@internal:registry=https://my.internal.registry/npm`

which lets me get our internal packages from our own repo, which isn't routed through the firewall.

Both of these work fine on their own.  The problem is, I can't access our own repo with that `cafile` setting.

You should be able to restrict the `cafile` setting to the public repo like this:

`//registry.npmjs.org/:cafile=/etc/ssl/cert.pem`

But that doesn't use `cafile` for either repo (bug?).

I'm using the following command to test:

`npm cache clear --force; npm view axios; npm view @internal/api`

Only one `view` works, depending on whether `cafile` is commented out or not.  (`view` uses the cache, which is why I clear it).  I can fix the test:

`npm cache clear --force; npm view axios; npm --cafile=- view @internal/api`

(Setting `cafile` to almost *anything* on the command line disables it).

However, my project needs a single config that lets me do `npm install` and get everything at once, rather than having to do it once with `cafile` and once without.